# after launching app How to reload tableview if any new content appears in array every time and if array is same then doesn’t need to reload

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My issue: I want to reload `tableview` data only once after launching app ,but it **reloads** every time the tableview appears and if array is same then it doesn’t need to reload again and again

```
func onHttpSuccess(data: NSDictionary, RID: Int) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.progressHUD.hide(animated: true)
    }
    if data.value(forKey: "status") as! Bool {

        if (RID == 1)
        {

            if ((data.value(forKey: "data") as? NSArray)?.count) != nil
            {
                self.userData = (data.value(forKey: "data") as? NSArray)!
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.userData, forKey: Constants.catDATA)

                print(self.userData)
                if self.userData.count > 0
                {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.tableView.isHidden = false
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Utility.sharedInstance.showAlertView(message: (data.value(forKey: "message") as? String)!, controllerObj: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: If response come from API then add field isChangeRequired as bool if change at backend then set true and reload tableview at frontend.

Comment: I've been try and its doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can u please update your code?So, we can see what are you doing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

One quite simple solution for you is just declare another variable for comparison purpose, so initially your temporary array will be empty and your actual array will be contain some elements so, you just compare both array and if both are same then you don’t need to do anything but if both are not same just reload your tableview and update the temporary array as well so it will be helpful for compare for next time as well. Please make sure you update temporary array after reload tableview.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, table view reloads should be treated as an inexpensive operation, and if you are experiencing some latency/unresponsiveness when the table view is reloaded, the first areas to look to would be:

1. Are the TableViewCells being dequeued rather than created each time they're needed?  If not dequeue the cached cells.
2. Is there some expensive operation happening inside `tableView(cellForRowAt:IndexPath)`?  If so look into making that faster.
3. Are you parsing your HTTP response on the main thread?  If so you that might be the source of the latency, not the table-view reload itself, so you can move it to the background and you're fine.

If *none* of these is the problem, and you're still getting poor UI performance due to table view reloads, then you can accomplish what you're asking about by comparing the new dataset you retrieve from the HTTP response to the existing table view data before deciding to reload.  The simplest way to do this is to keep a local variable as part of the table view controller and check against this in the HTTP request:

```
class MyTableViewController : UITableViewController {

    var tableViewData: NSArray

    func isEqual(_ oldData: NSArray, newData: NSArray) -> Bool {
        // check that all the records in the array are equal
    }

    // call this from inside the onHttpSuccess method in place of self.tableView.reloadData() 
    func reloadIfNeccecary(newData: NSArray) {
        if !isEqual(tableViewData, newData) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

**Note:** What you *really* should do instead of using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` here is to parse the HTTP response using a custom struct and the `Decodable` protocol.  Then you can make the array elements of your response object `Equatable` and then it will make implementing `isEqual` trivial.